# Yii2 Auth Client Api

Tags: yii2

i have plan about write Api Module for login by api. Detail, that another device can login with social account(Facebook, Google, etc..). So i not exact scenario for todo. 
First i have scenario:

1. Client Send token to server
2. Server receive token and clients name(facebook, google..) and receive user info.
3. Server store data and response to client
4. Client receive data and login

So, please share me detail or show me some document for more info.

Comment: You can [start here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient/blob/master/docs/guide/README.md)

Comment: That's too broad. It's unlikely to be solved in current state. :/